# components are separated when they are suppose to be in succession vertically

Tags: java, swing

I want the image and the title (JLabel) to both me centered and be at the top of the page but instead the image is at the top of the page and centered but the title is 3/4ths of the way down the page and centered.

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    c.insets = new  Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    panel.add(image,c);
    c.gridy = 1;
    panel.add(title, c);
```

Comment: Suggestion:  Add [gridbaglayout] tag to the question, and possibly the [swing] tag.

Comment: Also, best to post code that we can *fully* run, meaning a [mre] code post, also with additional text that tells the details of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
c.weighty = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(image,c);
c.gridy = 1;
panel.add(title, c);
```

You don't reset the "weighty" constraint so it is used for both components. Therefore, the "extra" space in the frame is allocated equally to each component. So you see the extra space between the two components.

Add a Border to each component and you will see the actual size of each component.

The solution is to assign set the "weighty" constraint to only the second component so the first component is displayed at its preferred size.

```
//c.weighty = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
panel.add(image,c);
c.gridy = 1;
c.weighty = 1;
panel.add(title, c);
```